# Suppress errors/warning in requests_cache

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using [requests_cache](https://github.com/requests-cache/requests-cache) to cache my Python HTTP requests. After the cache has expired, I don't want requests to fail right away if the user is offline; I'd rather allow some time during which requests_cache *tries* to fetch a new result, but uses the cache if unsuccessful. The parameter `stale_if_error` does this successfully (no error), but it still prints a big error/warning message to the screen:

```py
import requests_cache
import time
from datetime import timedelta

session = requests_cache.CachedSession(
    expire_after=timedelta(seconds=1),
    stale_if_error=timedelta(minutes=5),
)
session.cache.clear()

response = session.get("https://httpbin.org/get")
print(response.from_cache, response.is_expired)

# turn off network here
time.sleep(10)

response = session.get("https://httpbin.org/get", timeout=5)
print(response.from_cache, response.is_expired)
```

```
False False
[...]
<big fat error message>
requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=5)
[...]
True True
```

Any way to suppress that?

Comment: Is this a line printed to the console or a raised exception?

Comment: No exception is raied, it's just printed to console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `requests_cache` package is using the logging module to log warnings etc. You see the error there because of [this code](https://github.com/requests-cache/requests-cache/blob/c102ae50c7a601ed4d8eb129494faadc63b083e2/requests_cache/session.py#L277):

> ```py
> logger.warning(
>    f'Request for URL {cached_response.request.url} failed; using cached response',
>    exc_info=True,
> )
> ```

The default logging level for any logger is `WARNING` so you get that printed to the console. One simple solution is to set the logging level to `ERROR` in your script:

```py
import logging

requests_cache_logger = logging.getLogger('requests_cache.session')
requests_cache_logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```